# Python Web Scraping using Selenium 5 dropdowns resulting in 5 nested loops

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to **scrape** a data off a website, where you have 5 different dropdown. Once an option is selected from all dropdowns, a pdf file is downloaded. What I want to do is download all possible pdf files from all dropdown option combinations.

Now comes the tricky part, the only way to produce the pdf file is select from the 1st dropdown then 2nd then 3rd then 4th and finally 5th, where each dropdown is a subset of the previous dropdown. Initially only the first dropdown has a list of options, the rest are empty dropdowns with a null element each. The subsequent dropdown options only appear once an option from the previous dropdown has been selected.

From my understanding what I need is 5 nested loops, 1 loop for selecting each dropdown.
And the code block in each loop is essentially the same. So you have the same block of code repeated 5 times.

I understand nesting loops is generally not the best approach to do things, as more nested loops results in more n-s in my O-s, i.e. O(n).

The solution I have currently works however the execution time is quite long and the code itself is quite extensive and difficult to read.

```
xpath1 = "..."
xpath2 = "..."
xpath3 = "..."
xpath4 = "..."
xpath5 = "..."


dropdown_list1 = get_dropdown_options(driver, xpath1)   

    for dropdown_option in dropdown_list1:

        selected_value1 = select_dropdown_option(driver, xpath1, dropdown_option)

        # other code execution
        
        dropdown_list2 = get_dropdown_options(driver, xpath2)   

        for dropdown_option in dropdown_list2:

            selected_value2 = select_dropdown_option(driver, xpath2, dropdown_option)

            # other code execution
            
            dropdown_list3 = get_dropdown_options(driver, xpath3)   

            for dropdown_option in dropdown_list3:

                selected_value3 = select_dropdown_option(driver, xpath3, dropdown_option)

                # other code execution
                
                dropdown_list4 = get_dropdown_options(driver, xpath4)   

                for dropdown_option in dropdown_list4:

                    selected_value4 = select_dropdown_option(driver, xpath4, dropdown_option)

                    # other code execution
                    
                    dropdown_list5 = get_dropdown_options(driver, xpath5)   

                    for dropdown_option in dropdown_list5:

                        selected_value5 = select_dropdown_option(driver, xpath5, dropdown_option)

                        # other code execution
```

Is this the best way to do it? If not how can I improve overall code quality and execution time?

Comment: Probably looping through all possible outcomes one by one is the only solution here. To reduce the time taken you can use multiple webdriver instances concurrently (multi-threading).

Comment: If the website can show results by sending header values via the python's `requests` modules, then what you can do is extract all the possible values in the dropdown list(it is possible if there are small number of unique values). Then you can use heavy multithreading to get/post lots of requests to that website via the request headers.